# How to respond_to js.erb?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have this form with remote: true

```
<div id="new_review"></div>
<%= form_for @feedback, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area(:comment)" %>
  <%= f.submit("Submit") %>
<%end%>
```

It is going to this controller using ajax

```
def create
    @feedback = Feedback.new(feedback_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        @feedback.save
        format.html {}
        format.js {}
    end
end
```

I created a file **create.js.erb** in the feedbacks folder

```
$("#new_review").append("<h1>lallalalalala</h1>");
alert('js was called!');
```

On the server side the request is going through the controller and even rendering the create.js.erb - but nothing is happening.

```
Started POST "/feedbacks" for ::1 at 2016-03-04 18:43:29 +0100
Processing by FeedbacksController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "feedback"=>{"comment"=>"dasd"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "feedbacks" ("comment", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["comment", "dasd"], ["created_at", "2016-03-04 17:43:29.277992"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-04 17:43:29.277992"]]
   (6.0ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered feedbacks/create.js.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.slim (31.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_errors.slim (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 58ms (Views: 48.9ms | ActiveRecord: 6.4ms)
```

Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
```

I was googling it the whole day, was watching tutorials but couldn't make it work. I tried things like $.ajaxSetup in application.js and some ajax requests but no luck.

How does it work? Would appreciate also some great tutorials for ajax, js or any tips. Thank you.

Thank you,

Comment: I think you should put `@feedback.save` outside `respond_to do |format|`.
And did you put this line `//= require jquery_ujs` inside `application.js` ?

Comment: Thanks Khanh, I tried to put @feedback.save outside and in my application.js I require jquery, jquery_ujs & turbolinks. Not working.

Comment: Could you update your question to reflect the latest code? Could you paste the logs for the entire request? Including Processing by Controller#action as JS, etc.?

Comment: have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026998/execute-javascript-on-partial-render

Comment: The question was edited by further information - added: application.js and log from the server.

Comment: have you tried just `.js`, not `.js.erb`? Just trying to narrow down the possible error. Also, have you tried looking in your client console (web browser debugger tool) for errors?

Comment: Max, I tried to rename the file to .js but didn't help. I also looked to the client console and it's clear with no errors. Thank you anyway... any other tips?

Comment: So weird, i did it follow as your example and it worked as well on my computer. But i didn't understand why your code didn't work.

Comment: Yea:/ I didn't solve it yet. I guess everything is ok, there will be just something little why it isn't working. Here I am sharing the app: https://github.com/Dudisek/budeprace/tree/remote-true - maybe someone will discover something wrong there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936633/rails-update-js-erb-not-executing-javascript#comment27962824_18936633).

I solved the issue with a line of code in my controller respond format.js by adding this line: `{render layout: false}`

Another solution might be adding `data: {type: "script"}` to your form_for, but in my case it didn't work.

The working controller looks like this:

```
def create
    @feedback = Feedback.new(feedback_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        @feedback.save
        format.html {}
        format.js {render layout: false}
    end
end
```

Thanks everyone for being involved.

Answer (score 0):

Yo, I'm not too sure, but try substitute

```
respond_to do |format|
        @feedback.save
        format.html {}
        format.js {}
    end
```

to this

```
respond_to :js
```

Comment: but are you sure it keeps the same logic?

Comment: Tried but didn't help. Thanks anyway.)